# How to replace a static string with a variable and convert to long?

Tags: java

I have the following code to generate sequential Mac Addresses.  The code works well if I statically define the string when creating the hextint.  However, if I change the string to a variable, as seen below, I get an error:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "6CDFFB6000000A
"

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.  Why is the string as a variable not converting? Any help is appreciated.

```
    String macAddr = last_mac.getText();
//             int qty = Integer.parseInt(label_qty.getText());
             System.out.println("String to convert: " + macAddr);             
//             long hexint = Long.parseLong("6CDFFB60000000", 16);
             long hexint = Long.parseLong(macAddr, 16);

             System.out.println("String converted to Long:" +hexint);     
             System.out.println("10+ previous number:" + (10+hexint));
             System.out.println("Convert back to hex: " + Long.toHexString(10+hexint).toUpperCase());

        for(int i = 1; i < 10+1; i++){
            System.out.println(i +" MAC: " + Long.toHexString(hexint + i).toUpperCase());
            macAddr = Long.toHexString(hexint + i).toUpperCase();
        }
```

Comment: Try printing out `last_mac.getText()`. It looks like its not `6CDFFB60000000`

Comment: runs fine on my machine for `String macAddr = "6CDFFB6000000A";`

Comment: `For input string: "6CDFFB6000000A "` <-- Notice **trailing space**.

Comment: Looks like your address has a space at the end. Try to `trim` it

Comment: Missed the trailing space part. After trimming, it should work fine

Comment: Thanks everyone! I can't believe I overlooked that for the last few days! It works like a charm now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text contains a trailing space. You should remove it by `trim()` method. Try the following code & it should work for you.

```
String macAddr = last_mac.getText().trim();
```